# Increment a variable in JS and to got value outside of the function

Tags: javascript, scope

I am trying to code a quizz in JS, i try to increment a scoring variable and getting the value outside of the function, but i have a problem with scope. When i use console.log my variable is still = 0:

```js
let score = 0;

$qStart.click(() => {
  $qStart.remove();
  $quizzQ.add("div").addClass("question");
  $("question").add('div').addClass("timer");
  
  $quizzQ.text(quizz[idQ].prop + " ?");
  
  $trueR.click(() => {
    if (quizz[idQ].soluce === 1) {
      $quizzQ.text(positivesAnswers[getRandomInt(positivesAnswers.length)]);
      score++;
    } else {
      $quizzQ.text(negativeAnswers[getRandomInt(negativeAnswers.length)]);
    }
  });
  console.log(score);
});
```

Comment: Where's the `quizz` variable declared?

Comment: Did `score ++;` ever get called? Where did you try to `console.log` this variable?

Comment: Your `score` value is not incremented until whatever `$trueR` references is clicked.

Comment: @Pointy: I click on $trueR button, variable is still = 0

Comment: @izambl quizz is a const declared before the function

Comment: The `console.log()` call is *outside* the "click" handler though.

Comment: All is working except the score

Comment: @Pointy Right! If console.log is in the"click" handler, score increment, but i want to get the score outside. How can i do?